# interaction between Mirtazapine & Mesalamine & olanzapine

Tags: medications

Is there any adverse reaction or interaction between Mirtazapine & Mesalamine & olanzapine, If taken in low doses(mirtazapine 7.5 & Olanzapine 2.5).

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: Specifically, there are several web sites that offer interaction checkers, such as drugs.com and rxlist.com. You should be checking there before asking here.

Comment: @CareyGregory just wanted to make you aware of https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/39118. love to hear your thoughts because you said you worked in biotech.

Answer (score 1):

mirtazapine has a somewhat complex pharmacodynamic's: acts as an antagonist of the presynaptic alpha-2 autoreceptor and increases the release of both norepinephrine and seratonin; it is an antagonist of the 5-HT2 and 5-HT3 receptors; and it acts as a potent H1 antagonist, which is associated with the sedative effects of the drug.

olanzapine, is a second-generation antispychotics antagonist of 5HT2a and D2 receptors.

According to [drugs.com](https://www.drugs.com/mtm/mesalamine.html):

> Mesalamine affects a substance in the body that causes inflammation, tissue damage, and diarrhea. Mesalamine is used to treat mild to moderate ulcerative colitis. Mesalamine is also used to prevent the symptoms of ulcerative colitis from recurring.

**Interactions**

Major drug to drug interactions: mirtazapine is metabolized by several CYP450 enzymes (2D6, 3A4, 1A2). Therefore, drugs that inhibit these isoenzymes may cause an increase of mirtazapine levels (the same logic is applied to olanzapine). Also, the sedative effects of mirtazapine can be cumulative with CNS depressants, such as alcohol and benzodiazepines.

Minor interactions: according to [drugs.com](https://www.drugs.com/drug-interactions/mirtazapine-with-olanzapine-1640-0-1744-0.html) there is in fact an interaction between mirtazapine and olanzapine

> can increase the risk of an irregular heart rhythm that may be serious and potentially life-threatening, although it is a relatively rare side effect.

(can't find any bibliographic reference to support this conclusion though)

as much I was able to ascertain mesalamine does not interact with neither olanzapine nor mirtazapine.

**References:** basic and clinical pharmacology

Comment: Specially in those lower doses, I can't find any interrogation between the interaction of the drugs you have described